# I am not able to create base classes as per my requirement

Tags: java, hibernate

Below code is being used for money, it should be BigDecimal but, whenever I am trying to create these classes by synchronizing hbm file it is generating Integer type instead of BigDecimal.

```
public void setCompanyToUsRate (java.lang.Integer _companyToUsRate) {
        this._companyToUsRate = _companyToUsRate;
    }
```

I want BigDecimal as argument.
My hbm.xml is as follow :

```
<property name="SaCode" column="SA_CODE" type="string" not-null="false" length="8" unique="false" update="true" insert="true" />
<property name="Method" column="METHOD" type="string" not-null="false" length="16" unique="false" update="true" insert="true" /> 
<property name="ServiceTaxIva" column="SERVICE_TAX_IVA" type="integer" not-null="false" length="22" unique="false" update="true" insert="true" />
```

Comment: How does your hbm file look like?

Comment: <property name="SaCode" column="SA_CODE" type="string" not-null="false" length="8" unique="false" update="true" insert="true" /> 
  <property name="Method" column="METHOD" type="string" not-null="false" length="16" unique="false" update="true" insert="true" /> 
  <property name="ServiceTaxIva" column="SERVICE_TAX_IVA" type="integer" not-null="false" length="22" unique="false" update="true" insert="true" /> In property ServiceTaxIva, type is integer but I need BigDecimal.

Comment: @SatishMishra: Edit your post next time, instead of writing such things in a comment!

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void setCompanyToUsRate (java.lang.Integer _companyToUsRate) {
        BigDecimal temp = new BigDecimal(_companyToUsRate);
    this._companyToUsRate = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it not create the hbm-file correctly if you just use the BigDecimal-Type in your method??

```
public void setCompanyToUsRate (java.math.BigDecimal _companyToUsRate) {
    this._companyToUsRate = _companyToUsRate; // member has to BigDecimal as well of course
}
```

If not, you can hand-edit your hbm:

```
<property name="ServiceTaxIva" column="SERVICE_TAX_IVA" type="big_decimal" not-null="false" length="22" unique="false" update="true" insert="true" />
```

Actually changing the method signature should already work as expected...

Comment: Actually whne I am creating hbm file by default it is taking integer, once I change its type from integer to big_decimal, it is generating BigDecimal. Actual problem is in creation of hbm file, may be it is problem of templet or snippet. please help.

Comment: @SatishMishra Did you change your method-signature to BigDecimal and it is still generating integer in the hbm? What is your underlying database?